# Split - Join, Aggregate, Zip, LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, join, split, aggregate

**1st GUID** String:

```
A-B-C-D
```

**2nd GUID** String:

```
W-X-Y-Z
```

**3rd** Required **Reversible** String:

> **A**-W-**B**-X-**C**-Y-**D**-Z

**What**'s the best method to join 1st & 2nd to get 3rd then separate it to get both back?

Join-Split, Aggregate, Zip or others?

**Edit I**:
Maybe LINQ if every GUID is assumed to be `Enumerable<String>`
{ **A**, **B**, **C**, **D** } ?

Comment: [String.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) and [String.Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6d350wd.aspx)?

Comment: I tried String.Concat .. It's just joining the together not mixing them!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best method? I am not sure. but I find it a simple way.

```
string g1 = "A-B-C-D";
string g2 = "W-X-Y-Z";

var result = String.Join("-",g1.Split('-').Zip(g2.Split('-'), (a,b) => a+"-"+b));
```

**EDIT**

And to get back

```
int i=0;
var gs = result.Split('-').GroupBy(_ => i++ % 2).Select(g => String.Join("-",g))
               .ToList();
```

Comment: How to get `g1` & `g2` back ?

Answer (score 4):

```
string str1 = "A-B-C-D";
string str2 = "W-X-Y-Z";
```

To merge:

```
string merged = string.Join("-",
    str1.Split('-').Zip(str2.Split('-'), (a, b) => a + "-" + b).ToArray());
```

Result:

```
A-W-B-X-C-Y-D-Z
```

To split:

```
ILookup<int, string> split = merged.Split('-')
    .Select((a, i) => new { i = i, val = a })
    .ToLookup(x => x.i % 2, x => x.val);
string split1 = string.Join("-", split[0].ToArray());
string split2 = string.Join("-", split[1].ToArray());
```

Result:

```
A-B-C-D
W-X-Y-Z
```

Comment: +1 Follows the functional style of Linq better with no state mutation.

Comment: also, lol; this account is a chat bot. Looks like *someone* forgot to log out as their bot account... ;p

Answer (score 1):

I don't know "what's the best way" but you can do it with a simple "for" loop like this:

```
string a = "ABCD";
string b = "WXYZ";
string c = string.Empty;
if(a.Lenght == b.Lenght)//Check lenght
{
   for(int i = 0; i < a.Lenght; i++)
   {
      c += a[i] + "-" + b[i];
      if(i != a.Lenght)//If it isn't last character
      {
         c += "-";//Add a "-" end of "c"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This will include double dashes

Comment: Hello, I'm not looking for Simplicity. However, Thanks you for your interest :)

Comment: @AhmedGhoneim good works! :)

Comment: Try this with real GUIDs, like `2D548EEF-07BB-44E6-AC0F-BE2134D082BD`

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if the syntax is not 100%, C# is not my first language, but I would split each GUID into a List. Then a simple loop.

```
List<string> lstGuid1 = new List<string>;
List<string> lstGuid2 = new List<string>;
lstGuid1.AddRange(guid1.ToString().Split("-"));
lstGuid2.AddRange(guid2.ToString().Split("-"));
string guid3 = null;
if(lstGuid1.Length == lstGuid2.Length)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < lstGuid1.Length; i++)
  {
    guid3 += lstGuid1[i] + "-" + lstGuid2[i] + "-";
  }
  guid3 = guid3.Substring(0, guid3.Length - 1);
}
```